# Java 7 JVM VerifyError in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, java-7

When I compile my project in eclipse indigo using JDK 7, I get the following error dialog

[image]

with the following stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 32 in method ... at offset 0
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I've found a relevant bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339388) and used the suggested workaround of using jvm option `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` and although it works, this bug still confuses me.

Does anyone know why this is happening and why the workaround...works?

#### --Note--

The project compiles fine using JDK 6.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Bug 353467](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353467) speaks about "using `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to activate the old verifier".
That is consistent with the [JDK TM 6 Adoption Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/adoptionguide-137484.html) which describes that option as:

> Traditional verifier can be forced with the `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` flag.
>
> Missing or incorrect `StackMapTable` attributes for version `50.0` class files can result in `VerifyError` exceptions.
> Tools that rewrite bytecode in version `50.0` class files and do not correctly update the `StackMapTable` may fail to verify and trigger exceptions.

So the [comment from 2011-10-03](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353467#c3) does point out that:

> AspectJ now auto activates the previously optional setting to create stackmaps if the classes are Java7.

Comment: "*believed fixed.  AspectJ now auto activates the previously optional setting to
create stackmaps if the classes are Java7.  Please reopen if still an issue.*"...so I guess this is still an issue then?

Comment: @mre: in the current releases of Eclipse, it is possibly still an issue. But it should be fixed in the current 3.8M3/4.2M3 release.

Comment: I can't verify that the build fixes the problem because there's no AspectJ Development Tool available for Eclipse 3.8..:/

Comment: @mre surely you can add AspectJ as a plugin through one of the update site listed in http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/?

Comment: @mre: true so that would mean testing the latest AJDT with an Eclipse 3.7 (which might be already included in your Eclipse Indigo)

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem, I fixed it by deleting my JDK 1.7 system libraries from the project, and added the 1.6 JDK libraries instead. I went to run the project again, and I didn't get the error. When I added the JDK 1.7 libraries in again, it still works, so something in the 'swapping' makes it work.

Comment: The same happened with me! It is a workaround to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem in Juno, but resolved it by installing the latest 4.2 version from the 4.2 update site here:

http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/

That's the same one @VonC gave a year ago -- but since the updated AspectJ is there now (but not in the latest Juno repository nor with what is shipped with Spring), it now constitutes an answer.

But credit to @VonC.

Note that this should work for 3.8 as well as 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

currently, my environments is jdk 1.7(j2sdk 1.7 update 21) with eclipse 4.2 juno (SR2)
I had same problem, so I had fixed it which configured VM arguments Option '-XX:-UseSplitVerifier' 
but it has ocurred big trouble when I will deploy product based on google-app-engine.

finally I changed java 6 (update 43)